# Cómo instanciar clase en Kotlin sin usar apply

Tags: kotlin

En Kotlin tengo una clase definida así:

```
open class miClase {
  var atributo1: String = ""
  var atributo2: String = ""
  var atributo3: String = ""
}
```

Hasta ahora la estaba inicializando así:

```
val miObjeto = miClase().apply {
  atributo1 = "valor 1"
  atributo2 = "valor 2"
  atributo3 = "valor 3"
}
```

Que lo que hace realmente es dos pasos: instanciar la clase primero y luego aplicar los valores con `apply`. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo todo en un solo paso?

He intentado hacer algo como esto:

```
val miObjeto = miClase(
  atributo1 = "valor 1",
  atributo2 = "valor 2",
  atributo3 = "valor 3"
)
```

pero me da fallo al compilar diciendo que no puede encontrar ningún parámetro con esos nombres (atributo1, atributo2 o atributo3).

Comment: Hola Alvaro, o que me parece deseas es nstanciar la clase con ciertas propiedades, como un constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crear tu clase con un constructor y un bloque inicializador de la misma, por ejemplo:

```
open class miClase(atributo1: String, atributo2: String, atributo3: String) {
    val at1: String
    val at2: String
    val at3: String

     //Inicializador
    init {
        at1 = atributo1
        at2 = atributo2
        at3 = atributo3

        println("at1 = $at1")
        println("at2 = $at2")
        println("at3 = $at3")
    }
}
```

Al realizar la instanciación de la misma lo realizarías de esta forma, ejemplos:

```
val clase = miClase("Verde", "1.80", "lento")
val clase2 = miClase("Rojo", "1.60", "rapido")
val clase3 = miClase("Azul", "1.70", "lento")
```

Answer (score 1):

Después de buscar online, encontré la solución. El problema era cómo estaba definiendo la clase.

La nueva definición se vería así:

```
data class miClase (
  var atributo1: String = "",
  var atributo2: String = "",
  var atributo3: String = ""
)
```

Y la inicialización del objeto sería así:

```
val miObjeto = miClase (
  atributo1 = "valor1",
  atributo2 = "valor2",
  atributo3 = "valor3"
)
```

También cambie la clase para que fuera una data clase (aunque esto no es necesario, en mi caso parece conveniente). Las [data clases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) son clases que se utilizan principalmente para guardar datos y el compilador deriva algunos elementos a partir de las propiedades declaradas.